# Transfer a folder with subfolders from PC to Smartphone Note 3 via WLAN

Tags: file-transfer, ftp

I'd like to transfer a folder with approx. 300 files (wma, mp3 etc.) in different subfolders to the Galaxy Note 3 External SD Card.

I've tried some possible solutions:
WiFi File Transfer Pro: does not transfer the subfolder-structure
AirDroid: is too expensive (approx. 20 Dollars per year)
Kies Air: does not work neither

Is there any (almost) free solution?

I tried and it was possible per hazard with this one:
"ES Datei Explorer" App --> Activate ES FTP-Server
Installation of FileZilla on PC and open this WLAN Server Nummer
It was possible to tansfer whole subfolder structure

If someone knows an even bether or easier way (because in the way describes with FileZilla you cannot directly transfer to the external SD Card, you have to move on the smartphone afterward) please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of programs.  You're described the functionality of an FTP or SMB service.

One of the best is [Servers Ultimate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.serversultimatepro).

You might also take a look at [Airdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid).

Type this in the file explorer window of your OS to see a GUI resolution:

```
ftp://192.168.1.150:2121
```

*(The IP address should be replace for the one that Servers Ultimate Pro gives you.)*

You'll end up with a regular file browser window where you can drag and drop items between your computer and your Android.

This is a view of your drag/drop (copy option) in Linux:
[image]

This is a view of your drag/drop (copy option) in Windows:
[image]

The Android is on the left of the two pictures.  The PC is on the right of the two images.

When you drag and drop, you can drag and drop (transfer) **full subfolders** between the Android and the PC, or of course individual files.

**Enable write access for the user:**

Ensure you have setup a user for your ftp server and enabled write access for this user.  You can check this by clicking (from Servers Ultimate Pro):

- Click on Servers then Click the FTP server you setup
- Click Edit
- Click General
- Click Users
- Click the specific user
- Put Check mark in Allo write access

Comment: AirDroid (as desvribed above): unfortunately not useful, because 5 MB File Limitation

Servers Ultimate seems to be a cool tool, although ES File Explorer has also a FTP service

Comment: @user68212 Please look at what I added to the answer.  I thought this was inferred.  I believe you misunderstand the significants of an FTP server and the ftp client of ES File Explorer.

Comment: @user68212 I updated my answer to include an images in the description.

Comment: Thank you for the pictures. Unfortunately drag and drop is not possible (probably because of Update KitKat). Although it works very well with Samsung Kies 3.

Comment: @user68212 If you have a problem with drag and drop you, it's very obvious that you're doing something wrong.  The feature isn't depended on an OS version.  It is a default feature of ftp.  Depending on the error you get when you try, it might have something to do with some type of permission setting.  As far as update, I always run the latest updates on all my devices and encourage the same to my clients.  I'm glad you have the Kies workaround.  I tested it and removed it because of it bulkiness.  You're welcome for the images.  I thought you were missing the gist by your previous comment.

Comment: drag&drop from emulated/0/.. to PC = works

drag&drop from PC to emulated/0/.. = does not work

drag&drop from emulated/0/A/file.mp3 to emulated/0/B/ = does not work (without error)

renaming or deleting files from emulated/0 = works

-----
KitKat issue:

drag&drop from extSdCard/file.mp3 to PC = works

drag&drop from PC to extSdCard/file.mp3 = works

deleting extSdCard/file.mp3 = does not work
(error 450 RMD fail)

renaming extSdCard/file.mp3 = does not work
(350 Target exists, 550 RNTO failed)

drag&drop extSdCard/A/ to extSdCard/B/ = does not work
(without error notification)

Comment: how to add return between lines in this forum?

Comment: @user68212 It's disabled in the comment feature.  Extensive discussion is discouraged.  A user can modify his question or answer to make things clearer.  There are, however, limited formating tools available by clicking on the help to the right of your text box when commenting.  But newlines/carriage returns isn't one of them.

Comment: @user68212 I added a section to my answer **(enable write access)** that should resolve the issue you're describing.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!................................ OK = Click on Servers then Click the FTP server you setup...... OK = Click Edit ...... OK = Click General ..... OK = Click Users ..... OK = Click the specific user
..... OK = Put Check mark in Allo write access ................................................ so with this you can drag&drop files from pc to emulated/0. although you cannot delete rename or move files or data from extSdCard because no app has write access without rooting the smartphone. There are only two solutions: a) rooting your device b) connecting with Samsung Kies 3

Comment: @user68212 Performing the steps on the computer will enable write access.  Deleting a file is write access.  Rooting your android isn't a requirement for managing files and folders in your personal area and your SD card.  If you actually perform the steps and have problems I'd be curious.  I don't root my clients androids.  But I do set up their androids (as well as mine) for this ease of access.

Comment: With OK i meant that I have exactly done this steps in this order....If I click to the Servers Ultimate: Information: I reed: "Connect using an FTP client. It looks like you're not using root so you can't access the FTP server on the default port 21 which might cause problems connecting when using default settings. If you forward the port manually make sure you forward TCP. It seems that the FTP root is not writable, this might b a problem if you try to write files."....I used "FTP Server" (not Proxy or Native)....the "allow write access is only under specific and users able to click

Comment: in "GENERAL" should I Put Check mark in ROOT: Use root for internal port forwarding or something else because under root there is no "Allow write access" possible?....It would be nice if it really would work to have write access to the extSdCard (because my smartphone is not rootet)

Comment: @user68212 Don't setup ftp on the default port 21.  I never tried to do that.  It appears that the application is actually preventing you from making this security concerned issue.  My androids are not rooted.  I use them unrooted so that it would be easier for me to see what my clients see when giving them setup and configuration advise.  I gave you steps above in my answer.  I wouldn't advise forwarding since you're only setting it up for your local network.  I haven't even looked at the other things you're referencing.  Try the defailts with port 2121 and nothing else changed.

Comment: I've used port 21 and it was not working.

So now I have done it again and corrected your comment because most users do not already have Servers Ultimate with a user, so I first have to set up a user.

I've done exactly what I corrected in your answer, I navigated to the extSdCard in the file browser and tried to delete a folder then it occured the following notification:
Beim Löschen einer Datei oder eines Ordners auf dem FTP-Server ist ein Fehler aufgetereten. Stellen Sie sicher, dass Sie die erforderlichen Zugriffsrechte für den Ordner haben. Details:550 Deletion error, possibly incomplete"

Comment: @user68212 The answer I gave you would never fail.  If you changed my answer and have problems, I believe it might be due to the changes you made.  I when over the steps I typed in my answer a number of times while making preparing the answer.  I'll have to study what you have done different by studying whatever changes you made and put the answer back to what actually is deeply tested and works.  I'll hope that you'll try the update and give feedback on exactly the steps that I have tested.  It'll take me a while to study and redo the answer (with test).  I'll advise you when it's done.

Comment: I fixed the steps in a easy to follow manner.  If you can't get to the step of putting the check mark in the user, please indicate the last thing you did when you got stuck.  If you did add the check mark and still can't write, you might check how you configured the client.  I can go into more details with the client.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get ADB running on your computer (see e.g.: [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575))
2. Enable [wireless ADB](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=200) on your Android device
3. on a command line: `adb push <local_folder> <remote_folder>` to get the files from your computer to the Android device – or `adb pull <remote_folder> <local_folder>` for the other direction